# Creating dynamic tables with MySQLi securely

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to be able to create dynamic tables, for custom user surveys... like survey monkey... how would I go about create something like that?

Because I want to give the ability to the user to create the survey, with different amount of text fields, and different a option fields... I would need to create a custom table for each survey.

Would something like this be possible?

```
<?php

$table_name = 'survey_'.$_POST['surveyid'];

$query = 'CREATE TABLE ? (
            `responseid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `textarea1` TEXT NULL,
            `textarea2` TEXT NULL,
            `textarea3` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            `drop_down1` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            `drop_down2` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            `bool1` BIT NULL,
            `bool2` BIT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`responseid`))';

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $table_name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}else die("Failed to prepare");

?>
```

The above example comes back with `"Failed to prepare"`, because I don't think I can prepare a table name... is there another work around using mysqli?

```
if(ctype_digit($_POST['surveyid']) && $_POST['surveyid']>0){

    $table_name = 'survey_'.$_POST['surveyid'];

    $query = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.' (
            `responseid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `textarea1` TEXT NULL,
            `textarea2` TEXT NULL,
            `textarea3` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            `drop_down1` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            `drop_down2` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            `bool1` BIT NULL,
            `bool2` BIT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`responseid`))';
```

I know I can just try to sanitize the `$_POST['surveyid']` (like I did above) but I prefer to prepare it if possible.

Comment: It is possible to do as you are asking, to dynamically create a table.  However, you should consider if this is the best approach.  For two similar projects, instead of creating a table, I created an xml document and stored that in an XML data column.  (I can't remember if MySQL has this datatype, but you can use varchar).  To display the form, you then parse the xml and generate the tools dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table_name = 'survey_'.$_POST['surveyid'];
```

**Do not do the above.** It is easy for a hacker to exploit your site if you include $_GET or $_POST data directly in any SQL string.

But you can't use parameters for a table name. A parameter takes the place of a single scalar value *only*. [You can prepare `CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) but you can't use parameters for identifiers (e.g. table names).

The best practice is to make sure your table name conforms to a rule, for example only the leading portion of a string of numeric digits, up to the maximum length of a MySQL table name:

```
$table_name = 'survey_' . strspn(trim($_POST['surveyid']), '0123456789', 0, 56);
```

If you have other rules for a surveyid, then you could use preg_replace():

```
$table_name = 'survey_' . preg_replace('^(\w+)', '$1', trim($_POST['surveyid']));
```

Comment: What if I did `if(ctype_digit($_POST['surveyid']) && $_POST['surveyid']>0){` before `$table_name = 'survey_'.$_POST['surveyid'];` (like my second example)... is that still open for exploit?

Comment: Yes, that should be safe, since `ctype_digit()` checks *all* the characters in the string. But in spite of that, anyone inspecting the code will rightly be alarmed that you are copying an unaltered $_POST variable into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** possible to prepare a data definition language statement like "CREATE TABLE". I can't find the reference in the MySQL docs that explains this, but I did find a good explanation on the [PHP documentation site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#111977).